# What is exactly length_error in string and how to remove it

Tags: c++, algorithm, coding-style

I made the following code and when I execute it I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_S_create
>
> 0Aborted (core dumped)

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    bool comp(char c1, char c2)
    {
          return c1 < c2;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
            string str;
            getline(cin,str);
            sort(str.begin(), str.end(), comp);
            int k;
            long long int sum40=0,sum41=0;
            scanf("%d",&k);
            cout<<str.length();
            for(unsigned int i=0;i<str.length();++i)
            {
                if(str[i]=='(')
                    sum40++;
                else
                    sum41++;
            }
            if(sum40!=sum41 && k==1)
                cout<<str;
            else
            if(sum40!=sum41 && k!=1)
                printf("-1");
            else
                {
                    while(k>0 || (sum40==sum41))
                    {
                        str.erase(str.begin());
                         k--;
                    }
                    cout<<str;
                }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to know what is std::length_error error and how do i remove that.

I know it is common problem. I saw a bunch of article on this but those article did not solve my problem.

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Do not use the C-tag for C++ questions. They are different languages!

Comment: I want to know on which line the error occurs. And also why you keep erasing a character from the string an infinite number of times when k>0 and sum40==sum41. Also, are you sure the input consists only of `(` and `)` characters, otherwise the variable names don't make sense.

Comment: Do you have a debugger?

Comment: @Mr ListerAfter I give input:
5
()
after this the error appears
and sorry for that K mistake It was a coding error

Comment: @rghome I work on gcc/g++

Answer (score 0):

It means the string you are trying to create is larger than std::string::max_size(). See the Remarks section in the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4axahk(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Need more explanation
How may I control the size of string I create

Comment: @user3774755 "How may I control the size of string I create": By not creating a string too long?

Answer (score 0):

You can change string capacity using the string::reserve function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/